# XPage Widget with extension.xml

Tags: widget, xpages, lotus-notes

I am just developing an XPage Widget with a manifest extension.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webcontextConfiguration version="1.1">
    <palleteItem title="XWidget" viewImageUrl="" url="notes://venus/xxx/Dev/Source/CC/CC_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/streamCC.xsp?
              OpenXPage&1536921419?OpenXPage=null" singletonSidebar="false"
          providerId="com.ibm.notes.toolbox.provider.XPagesPalleteProvider" imageUrl="" id="1385849393" hideThumbnail="false" 
              contributeToSideshelfOnStartup="true" contributeTabOnStartup="false">
        <preferences/>
        <data/>
    </palleteItem>
</webcontextConfiguration>
```

I have already researched the meaning of the different parts. Only the parameters of the URL "notes://venus/xxx/Dev/Source/CC/CC_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/streamCC.xsp?**OpenXPage&1536921419?OpenXPage=null**" are not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug during URL generation, but the bug has no consequences.

The URL parameters are splitted into two elements:

1. **OpenXPage**
2. **1536921419?OpenXPage=null**

While the meaning of the first parameter should be clear, the second one is to prevent caching (but is useless when "hardcoded" like in bookmarks)

**1536921419** is a unix timestamp to prevent caching.

```
GMT: Friday, 14. September 2018 10:36:59
```

**?OpenXPage=null**

Looks like a simple coding error. "Add ?OpenXPage=[value] if URL parameter OpenXPage is null or empty".